# How to monitor cnodes from erlang nodes

Tags: erlang, cnode

I've been building an application based on the cnode tutorial http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html and all is looking fine - my question however is, is there a way to do something similar to `nodes()` or `net_adm:world()` to get a list of the cnodes connected?

At the moment I'm not able to see the node using either command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C nodes are [**hidden**](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id83626). They are listed by [`nodes(connected)` and `nodes(hidden)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#nodes-1) once they are connected to the node.

This is on purpose to simplify implementation on the C side. Nodes that are listed in `nodes()` must implement many features including a global server.

If you really want your C node to appear in `nodes()`, you will have to extend the behavior of your node significantly and handle many system messages. Yet this is doable, you can rewrite the erl_interface function `erl_publish` which eventually calls `ei_epmd_r4_publish` which, in turn, [publishes your node as hidden](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP_R16B02/lib/erl_interface/src/epmd/epmd_publish.c#L83).

Comment: this almost answers my question, I do however have a follow up, why does my cnode first appear nodes(hidden) after I've done call to it?

Comment: When you make a call to the C node, you connect to it and therefore the node is then listed by `nodes(connected)` and `nodes(hidden)` which is a sublist thereof. `net_adm:names/0` lists both connected and unconnected but visible nodes.